# what is the best way to Upload a file to a php webservice and save it to mysql database?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm creating a PHP web service that saves files to MySql database.

The client side of my application is Android.

What is the proper way to upload a file(image, pdf, etc.) from android and save it to MySql database using PHP?

I'm not looking for codes right now, just wondering how I can do that?

Comment: You normally don't store files in the database. Save the file to some location (local or cloud) and save the filename in the database

Answer (score 1):

The android can use the base64 to encode the img. Then you create a post http request to your php server.Your php save the base64 code to the mysql.
When you read the img.You can decode base64 to img.
Note:If you encode a img to base64 the base64 code size will bigger then img.

Comment: Can I use base64 for any file type, or just for images?

Comment: Yes,you can encode any files to base64.But if your file is big I suggest you encode the file to Binary and save the binary.

Comment: And another way is you can put your img to the AWS server or aliyun oss. put the img on a cloud server.If so you not have to save the img to the mysql